# Montar menu responsivo com CSS

Tags: html, css

Galera montei um menu bem simples, porém não sei como colocar ele para ser responsável.

O problema que estou tendo é o seguinte. O 2º menu esta ok, porém o primeiro gera uma quebra de linha, pois existe muitas opções, eu preciso de fazer com que o `background: #616161;` acompanhe e quebra de linha. Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

```css
.menu_topo_geral {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #616161;
  margin-left: -10px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 500;
}
.menu_topo_geral_linha {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  line-height: 50px;
  float: left;
  border-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-color: #484848;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.menu_topo_geral_linha:hover {
  background: #484848;
}
.menu_topo_geral_linha:active {
  background: #323232;
}
.menu_topo_geral_espaco {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class='menu_topo_geral'>

  <div class='menu_topo_geral_linha'>Entrada</div>
  <div class='menu_topo_geral_linha'>Saída</div>
  <div class='menu_topo_geral_linha'>Transferência</div>
  <div class='menu_topo_geral_linha'>Fechar Caixa</div>
  <div class='menu_topo_geral_linha'>Entrada</div>
  <div class='menu_topo_geral_linha'>Saída</div>
  <div class='menu_topo_geral_linha'>Transferência</div>
  <div class='menu_topo_geral_linha'>Fechar Caixa</div>

</div>
<div class='menu_topo_geral_espaco'></div>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<div class='menu_topo_geral'>

  <div class='menu_topo_geral_linha'>Entrada</div>
  <div class='menu_topo_geral_linha'>Saída</div>
  <div class='menu_topo_geral_linha'>Transferência</div>


</div>
<div class='menu_topo_geral_espaco'></div>
 <br><bR><br><br>
```

Comment: Tecnicamente inviável, pois há hoje no mercado frameworks de CSS que te auxiliam na produção de um software totalmente responsivo. Como por exemplo - Bootstrap -

Comment: entendo, porém acho inviável usar uma frameworks para uma coisa tão simples quanto esse menu

Comment: @Hugo coloque o height da classe .menu_topo_geral como auto. Você deixou fixo com 50px então o background nunca vai acompanhar as divs que forem para baixo, pois acabam ultrapassando esses 50px.

Comment: ok blz ;) deu certo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizando o Plugin [Responsive-nav](https://github.com/viljamis/responsive-nav.js) isso é feito de uma maneira simples e sem usar framework como o BootsTrap.

Tem outras opções também como a dica do @Bruno

> @Hugo coloque o height da classe .menu_topo_geral como auto;

Porém tem que ter muito cuidado com as boas práticas na hora de tornar alguma parte de um site responsiva.

**Vamos ao que interessa.**

```css
@-webkit-viewport { width: device-width; }
@-moz-viewport { width: device-width; }
@-ms-viewport { width: device-width; }
@-o-viewport { width: device-width; }
@viewport { width: device-width; }

.nav-collapse ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-collapse li {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.js .nav-collapse {
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  max-height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  zoom: 1;
}

.nav-collapse.opened {
  max-height: 9999px;
}

.disable-pointer-events {
  pointer-events: none !important;
}

.nav-toggle {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .js .nav-collapse {
    position: relative;
  }
  .js .nav-collapse.closed {
    max-height: none;
  }
  .nav-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
}

header {
  background: #616161;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.logo {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 55px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
}

.mask {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 300ms;
  transition: opacity 300ms;
  background: rgba(0,0,0, .5);
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.android .mask {
  -webkit-transition: none;
  transition: none;
}

.js-nav-active .mask {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .mask {
    display: none !important;
    opacity: 0 !important;
  }
}

fixed {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.nav-collapse,
.nav-collapse * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nav-collapse,
.nav-collapse ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .nav-collapse {
    float: right;
    width: auto;
  }
}

.nav-collapse li {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .nav-collapse li {
    width: auto;
  }
}

.nav-collapse a {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #616161;
  padding: 0.7em 1em;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.nav-collapse a:active,
.nav-collapse .active a {
  background: #323232;
}
.nav-collapse a:hover,
.nav-collapse .hover a {
  background: #484848;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .nav-collapse a {
    border-left: 1px solid white;
    padding: 1.02em 2em;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 0;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
  }
}

.nav-collapse ul ul a {
  background: #484848;
  padding-left: 2em;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .nav-collapse ul ul a {
    display: none;
  }
}


.nav-toggle {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: -300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 60px;
  height: 55px;
  float: right;
}

.nav-toggle:before {
  color: #fff; /* Edit this to change the icon color */
  font: normal 28px/55px "responsivenav"; /* Edit font-size (28px) to change the icon size */
  text-transform: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  content: "\2261"; /* Hamburger icon */
  text-indent: 0;
  speak: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.nav-toggle.active:before {
  font-size: 24px;
  content: "\78"; /* Close icon */
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <script src="http://www.barietoner.com.br/js/responsive-nav.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <header>
      <a href="#home" class="logo" data-scroll>Menu</a>
      <nav class="nav-collapse">
        <ul>
          <li class="menu-item active"><a href="#home" data-scroll>Inicio</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="#about" data-scroll>Sobre</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="#projects" data-scroll>Projetos</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="#blog" data-scroll>Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <script src="http://www.barietoner.com.br/js/fastclick.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.barietoner.com.br/js/scroll.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.barietoner.com.br/js/fixed-responsive-nav.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Por causa do snippet do Stack o menu não ficou aparentemente funcional, mas ele está funcionando e pode ser visto [aqui](http://www.barietoner.com.br/js/exemplo).

> Para verificar como ficaria o menu em diferentes resoluções, você pode
>   redimensionar a janela do navegador, utilizar CTRL + SHIFT + M (google
>   chrome) ou verificar ferramenta do desenvolvedor do seu navegador ;)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tornar ele responsivo,utilizando o framework Bootstrap,ou se quiser otimizar ele para dispositivos movéis,deixo a dica do`@media screen and e então você coloca a otimização da página..Vou deixar como por exemplo,uma parte do código de minha pagina..

```css
 @media screen and (max-width: 768px) 
    {
  .asocial-area {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }
    .container{
        background-color:rgba(0, 51, 102,0.5);
        width: 82%;
              height:auto;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 31px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    body{
        background-image:url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/2440079/pexels-photo-2440079.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260");
        margin-left: 100px;
    background-size: 170%;
        margin-top: 77%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 92%;
        border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 150px;
    }
    h1{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color:aquamarine;
    text-align: center;
font-size:60px;
        margin-top: -66px;
}
    input[type="text"],input[type="password"]{
        align-content: center;
    height: 45px;
    width: 214px;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
}
    .btn-login{
        margin-bottom: auto;
  padding: 9px 14px;
      cursor: pointer;
    color:#fff;
    border: none;
    background-color:darkslategrey;
    border-bottom: 4px solid  darkslategrey;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
    .telacima{
        margin-top: -66px;
    }
```

Ele permite que você otimize sua página de forma diferente para dispositivos móveis. E uma opção para ajudar a fazer uma página responsiva,é o inspecionar elemento,ele possui um ícone para diferentes dispositivos.